# does kafka count log.retatantion since message was published or sinse server started

Tags: apache-kafka

in case I set log.retantion to 24 hours , one message was published at 1.1.24 15:30.
then the server was down for 25 hours and started again at 2.1.24 16:30, will the message be deleted immediately when the server starts or it will wait again 24H and will delete at 3.1.24 16:30?

this question is relevant also for restoring old backup of kafka with messages older than the configured log.retantion, will they be able to consumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kafka message deletion is based on timestamp attached to message/event and retention period. So in your case, since the retention period is 24 hours and server was down for almost 25 hours, it will be deleted immediately as soon as server comes up.

On other question, consumers won't get the messages if it is already dropped from broker as per its retention policy. I think, few things can be done here like increasing the retention period, producing or picking the messages again from backed-up storage.